# When does Pug tell Miranda this?

Tags: continuity, raymond-e-feist

I've finally got around to reading Wrath of a Mad God by Raymond E. Feist, and I just got to chapter 4 in which Sezu, the Emperor of the Tsurani, shows Miranda a note from Pug from the future. This is similar to notes that Pug himself has been receiving. Miranda reacts as if she knows about these notes:

> 'Another of those damned notes!' Miranda wasn't irritated by the fact that notes kept appearing mysteriously from some future date - warnings of threats, instructing them on actions to take - she was annoyed that they were always cryptic...

However, in chapter 2 of Into a Dark Realm, the previous book in the series, Pug narrates this:

> Nakor had been the first person he had told of the messages - just in the last year - though the box was still known only to Pug. Miranda thought it merely a decorative item.

Which I read to mean that Miranda also knew nothing of the notes. Then in chapter 11:

> Pug had weighed for months whether to tell his family about the notes from the future, but caution always prevented it.

Which seemed to confirm that he still hadn't told Miranda. Am I reading this wrong, and Pug has indeed told Miranda about the notes (and therefore about why he has gone to the Dasati homeworld)? Or have I missed him telling her somewhere else in one of the books? Or is this just poor continuity?

Comment: Wait, there are Feist books I haven't read yet? About Pug even? Why has nobody told me this?

Comment: @MrLister There are indeed, if you've not read them sorry for the slight spoiler! Wrath of the Mad God is the 3rd book of the Darkwar Saga, and there are a further 5 books in the Riftwar Cycle that I'm still yet to read.